# .NET, Visual Studio 2008, SVN - Reading revision number at compile time?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svn, version-control

Does any one know if there is a way to access a solution/project's revision number from SVN and incorporate this in application code at compile time?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the version number as assigned by Visual Studio or do you want the revision number from SVN to be added to the projects version number? i.e Library version 1.0.0.5645 - where 5645 is the SVN revision number?

Comment: @MrEyes, I want the SVN number, but if it this was automatically assigned to the VS project version some how that would be an acceptable approach.

Answer (score 8):

> ***Disclaimer:** I was a member of the project at the time of writing this. Though, I still recommend AutoBuildVersion.*

Yes, [AutobuildVersion](http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/) does together with the [SVN PlugIn](http://happyturtle.codeplex.com/) provide such a functionality.

Comment: This will blow up as soon as your revision number reaches 65536.

Comment: @Wim Coenen: Yes. But, don't get me wrong, one of the oldest and [most active](http://sourceforge.net/top/mostactive.php) projects on Sourceforge, [Crystal Space](http://sourceforge.net/projects/crystal/), 'only' has [35,000 commits](http://sourceforge.net/projects/crystal/develop). I think you should deal with that problem (in form of a Feature Request at [Happy Turtle](http://happyturtle.codeplex.com/)) the moment it comes so far.

Comment: @Bobby: what would that feature request be? "Change windows to accept  file version components larger than 65535"? I considered doing a `mod 10000` on the version number, but that sure will be awkward if the version number *decreases* during rollovers.

Comment: @Wim Coenen: I have no idea, maybe a modificator-option, like splitting it up in two pieces or increasing Revision with every rollover or something like that.

Comment: @Bobby: also, revision numbers can easily reach such numbers when you put many projects in one big repository (which is what we do). See the [repository of the apache software foundation](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/) (which hosts subversion itself) for an example.

Comment: @Wim Coenen: Splitting would work in that case: `x.x.105.2193` or `x.x.1052.193`. As I said, that would make a nice discussion/feature request over at Happy Turtle.

Comment: @Bobby: is there also a Git plugin for BVI?

Comment: @eckes: None I know of. But Happy Turtle is a PlugIn repository, so if you find the time grimus will be for sure happy if you can help him with a Git plugin.

Comment: +1 I installed this right after reading this answer, and so far, it seems to "just work" - exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your SVN version is the same as project assembly version

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.Revision
```

or, for some assembly which has Sometype

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SomeType)).GetName().Version.Revision
```

Comment: I think that's exactly the problem he has, he wants to set the Assembly version to the SVN revision.